# Does a byte oriented FILE stream contain `char`s or `unsigned char`s?

Tags: c, stdio

I have read through the C11 standard, section 7.21 where `<stdio.h>` is described. The standard first describes streams as:

7.21.2.2:

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters ...

7.21.2.3:

> A binary stream is an ordered sequence of characters ...

Which doesn't specify the type of the stream characters (since this depends on orientation). It later says:

7.21.3.12:

> ... The byte output functions write characters to the stream as if by successive calls to the fputc function.

From `fputc` (7.21.7.3.2):

> The `fputc` function writes the character specified by `c` (converted to an `unsigned char`) to the output stream pointed to by `stream` ...

Which indicates the `int c` argument of `fputc` is converted to an `unsigned char` before being written to the stream. A similar note is given for `fgetc`:

7.21.7.1.2:

> the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int`

and `ungetc`, `fread` and `fwrite`.

Now this all hints that internally, a byte oriented stream is represented by `unsigned char`s.

However, looking at the internals of the Linux kernel, it seems like files are considered to be streams of `char`. One reason I am saying this is that the [file_operations](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.6-rc6/include/linux/fs.h#L1777) `read` and `write` callbacks get `char __user *` and `const char __user *` respectively.

In the implementation of `glibc`, `FILE` is a `typedef` of `struct _IO_FILE` which is defined in `libio/libio.h`. In this `struct` also, all read and write pointers are `char *`.

In C++, the [`basic_ostream::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) function takes `const char *` as input and similarly `basic_istream::read` (but I'm not interested in C++ in this question).

My question is, **do the quotes above imply that FILE streams should be threated as streams of `unsigned char`? If so, why does the `glibc` and the Linux kernel implement them with `char *`? If not, why does the standard insist on converting the characters to `unsigned char`?**

Comment: One of the possible returns of `fgetc` is an error code (in the form of `EOF`). To distinguish the error code from any valid character, the Standard says the characters are converted to `unsigned char`, then to `int`. So there is absolutely no way to interpret `EOF` as a valid char or any valid char as an error code.

Comment: @pmg, That was a good point. For `fgetc` that makes sense because for example `-1` as a character would be returned as `255`. For `fputc` or `ungetc` where they convert from `int` to `unsigned char` however, I don't see any benefit. I mean, if you are storing them as `char`, then `char c = (unsigned char)i` and `char c = i` (`i` is the `int` input) are equal, isn't that correct?

Comment: Simmetry is a good characteristic to pursuit :)

Comment: @pmg, I completely agree with _that_!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really matter. The standard use unsigned char at some chosen place because it allows precise formulation at those places:

- `fgetc` is specified to return a unsigned char converted to an int so that one knows that the result is positive or null excepted when it is EOF (and thus there is no confusion possible between EOF and a valid char, confusion which is cause of bugs when one store directly the result of fgetc in a char without checking for EOF beforehand).
- `fputc` is specified to take an int and convert it to an unsigned char because this conversion is well specified. If you aren't careful, formulation not using unsigned char could make UB a sequence like

  ```
  int c = fgetc(stdin);
  if (c != EOF)
      fputc(c, stdout);
  ```

with signed char for negative chars.

Comment: Assuming the implementation of `FILE` uses `char` as the basis of stream, how would the code above yield undefined behavior? For example, if inside `fputc`, the character is going to be stored in `char x`, then wouldn't `x = (unsigned char)c` and `x = c` be equal?

Comment: @Shahbaz, if the standard didn't say what is mandated, it would have been undefined. And undefined is undefined, even if the most obvious implementation is well defined.  For the better or the worse, implementations tend to do non obvious things and take advantage of any lenience present in the standard. (BTW signed char = int can raise a signal, so the obvious implementation isn't so well defined here, but that's accessory to the point).

Comment: _signed char = int can raise a signal_, thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter. A `char` is **`CHAR_BIT`** bits long (`limits.h` - usually 8 bits), whether it's signed or not.

Those functions work with `CHAR_BIT` bits chunks, so the sign does not make a difference here, for the writing or reading process.

You may then use signed or unsigned chars, depending on your application logic, by appropriately casting the result. Human representation will be different, depending on the sign, but for the processor, the representation does not change. It's still bytes.

Comment: char is not necessary 8 bits. it is *at least* 8 bits.

Comment: Why wouldn't the standard then simply say _converted to `char`_ instead of _converted to `unsigned char`_?

Comment: a `char` is `CHAR_BIT` bits long (remember to `#include <limits.h>`).

Comment: Correct. Added CHAR_BIT instead of 8 bits.

Comment: @Shahbaz Because `char` is allowed to be either signed or unsigned, it's up to the compiler. Saying `unsigned char` removes an ambiguity here.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can directly observe (without checking the source) is what the API returns. Whatever is behind it is hidden by the black box abstraction, and shouldn't be your concern.

Regarding the other part of your question: The standard *has* to note, that there's a conversion, because the argument / return value is `int` and the stream is sequence of characters.

Comment: Actually it _is_ of my concern. I am writing a (kind of) [port of `stdio.h`](https://github.com/ShabbyX/kio) as a kernel module, therefore I need to be completely standard and aware of the details. If you are interested, I am doing so to solve my problem as mentioned in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9831567/912144).

Comment: If you were interested what the *Linux kernel* internally does, you should have asked a specific question...

Comment: No, I am interested in what the standard mandates, but I was saying that it was of my concern because I am implementing stdio, which happens to be in the Linux kernel.

Comment: Then I already answered your question. The C standard doesn't specify this.